# Solve a differential equation

Tags: differential-equations

I have a differential equation, that is difficult (or imposible) to solve in Mathematica. Anybody can help me with this? The differential eq. is: (x^2-x)*y''[x]-(n^2+m^2*x*(x-1))-Px(x-1)==0, y[0]==0, y[1]==0, y[x],x

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you post actual code so we can see what you have tried?

Comment: DSolve[{(x^2 - x)*y''[x] - (n^2 + m^2*x*(x - 1)) - Px (x - 1) == 0}, 
 y[0] == 0, y[1] == 0, y[x], x]

Comment: y[0]==0 cannot be used as a function

Comment: Hello bill s 1: This the answer of Mathematica software. I was treating to transform the factor x(x-1) in other, like this z = 2*(x-0.5), thus the new dif. eq is: (z^2-1)*y''[z]-(n^2+m^2*(z^2-1))y[z] - 0.25*P*(z^2-1).Where n, m and P are constants. The result is the same. What can I do to solve this eq.?

Comment: You have the parentheses in wrong place. Try `DSolve[{(x^2-x)*y''[x]-(n^2+m^2*x*(x-1))-Px (x-1)==0,y[0]==0,y[1]==0},y[x],x]` also it is confusing to have a parameter called `Px` in there. Are you sure you did not mean `P x`? Space is important in Mathematica.

Comment: I solved this dif eq. by numerical Galerkin and 1/3 and 2/3 methods. The approx. sol. was: y[x] =9*P*y*(y-1)/(-18+2*m^2-9*n^2) for 1/3 and 2/3 Method and y[x] = 5*P*y*(y-1)/(-10+m^2-5*n^2) for Galerkin Method.

Comment: Hi Nasser, thanks for your comment. Please, treat you of solve the dif. eq. with your observation. I treat to solve with all changes. I wrote quickly the eq. and has the error how you say. Perhaps, Mathematica no solves the dif. eq. I think I need other method to solve analytically. What do you say?

Comment: I am sorry, I am not able to understand your question. May be you can re-write your original question again, and make sure to post the exact code you used and explain what is the problem. As I showed, the ODE can be solved my Mathematica. You just had syntax error.

Comment: @Nasser: this is the dif. eq.                                                              
 DSolve[{-(y*(y - 1)*M^2 + n^2)*u[y] + y*(y - 1)*u''[y] == y*(y - 1)*P,
   u[1] == 0, u[0] == 0}, u[y], y], where P, n and M are constants. Mathematica has no solve this.

Comment: Maple gives this solution `u(y) = exp(m*y)*y*HeunC(2*m, 1, -1, 0, -n^2+1/2, y)*_C2+exp(m*y)*y*HeunC(2*m, 1, -1, 0, -n^2+1/2, y)*(Int(exp(-2*m*y)/(y^2*HeunC(2*m, 1, -1, 0, -n^2+1/2, y)^2), y))*_C1-exp(m*y)*y*HeunC(2*m, 1, -1, 0, -n^2+1/2, y)*P*(-(Int(exp(m*y)*y*HeunC(2*m, 1, -1, 0, -n^2+1/2, y), y))*(Int(exp(-2*m*y)/(y^2*HeunC(2*m, 1, -1, 0, -n^2+1/2, y)^2), y))+Int(exp(m*y)*y*HeunC(2*m, 1, -1, 0, -n^2+1/2, y)*(Int(exp(-2*m*y)/(y^2*HeunC(2*m, 1, -1, 0, -n^2+1/2, y)^2), y)), y))`

Comment: @Nasser, thanks a lot.